# USB connection problem

Tags: usb

I have a problem with my Samsung p1010, I started backing up my files prior to having it updated in a Samsung service center.  After updating it, my files were gone, lucky i had it backed up.  However, when I connected my device into my PC, it did not detect it like before.  I cannot open the folder for the tab, and the tab just went to connecting to MTP or something.

Comment: try to re-install the USB driver using samsung Kies...

Answer (score 5):

Go to settings -> wireless and network -> usb settings. Disable usb debugging if prompted, and select the usb mode you want. Kies for syncing with the kies application on the desktop, or mass storage for mounting the /sdcard and /sdcard/external_sd partitions.